# How can I create a growing object in WebGL and Three.js and Tween.js

Tags: animation, three.js, tween.js

I am new to Three.js and Tween.js. 
And I want to create an animation which an object could "grow": like an animation of 3D ball grows into a tube (or the 3D ball been dragged into the tube).

Can this been created by THREE.ExtrudeGeometry and Tween.js? If yes,
can I have some detail explanation or simple steps for this?

I'll be really appreciate for any better ideas.    :)

Thank you very much.

Brs,
Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your looking to do is alter the size of an object that can be accomplished by adjusting it's scale.

objectsName.scale.set( xValue, yValue, zValue );

However based on your description it seems like your looking to morph your object. There's a great example of how this can be accomplished located at threejs.org.

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your answer. That helps, can I ask you some more questions? For the example  http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets    The cube could morph to one direction (one morph target), and could animate like "mesh.morphTargetInfluences[ direction ]". But for the SphereGeometry, how to morph the sphere? Like dragging the ball into a tube?

Comment: Sorry I'm not quite sure how to morph a sphere into a cylinder. First I would create a cylinder located at 0,0,0 and push the location of all the vertices into an array. Make sure both the starting sphere and the ending cylinder have the same number of vertices. I'm not sure how to do that. Maybe with tessellation or subdivision. Then use tween.js to move all the vertices of the sphere to the location of the cylinder array.